# how to configure and enable xml return type from webmethod in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I think it might be configuration issue but i cannot figure it out why I am able to make a call from ajax if contentType is "Json" but if i change it to xml it does not call that webmethod. Can someone Please help.

**Below code is not working.**

**In JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Test.aspx/GenerateXML",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result)
        },
        error: function (error, e1, e2) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

**C# in aspx.cs page**

```
[WebMethod]    
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = true)]
    public static DataTable GenerateXML()
    {
        TestCalculator testCalculator = new TestCalculator();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable = testCalculator.GetValue("Test");

         return dataTable;
    }
```

**Working Code**
**In JavaScript**

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "Json",
        contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Test.aspx/GenerateXML",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result)
        },
        error: function (error, e1, e2) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

**C# Code**

```
[WebMethod]    
    public static DataTable GenerateXML()
    {
        TestCalculator testCalculator = new TestCalculator();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable = testCalculator.GetValue("Test");

         return dataTable;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are returning DataTable as-is, try to return XML string, Call datatable.GetXML()

Comment: @Brijesh it did not work, for some reason when i try to call from ajax with xml it always goes to error handler and returns html version of the page. It does not even hit the break point in the webmethod.

Comment: And what error does it throw? It should contain valuable info to fix the problem

Comment: Have you changed the return type of your webmethod, As rightly pointed out by Enrique, Please share the error details too.

Comment: I have attached the error screen with my question.

Comment: it is returning entire HTML and that is why it is causing the error. Have you changed the return type of your WebMethod

Comment: I did tried with string return type but still it gives me same result. not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: One more thing i found is if i move this webmethod to asmx page it works but if it is in aspx page it is not working.